# How do I keep J_____ methods sizes and location from keeping relevant with the JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, location, size, jframe

Hello everyone who is here by reading my post.  I am having some trouble with JFrame when using setLocation(); and setSize(); on J_*_*_ methods.  The size of everything I make is always the size of whatever the JFrame is set to as well as its location.  Does anyone know why I cannot set the location or size in JFrame of anything?

I asume there is no point in me sending the source code since its pretty straight forward and I am sure plenty of people out there know whats up, but if I need to I will.

Comment: Are you adding all of your components directly onto the JFrame? If so look into using multiple JPanels and as @AndrewThompson says below a layout manager is an unbelievable helpful tool when working with this sort of thing.

Comment: 1) Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with layout padding & borders for white space. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out.  To set locations and sizes on your own you must set the layout to null or just use another layout built in to JFrame.

Another way is to use:

```
component.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x,y));
```